# Clover code coverage of classes deployed in WebLogic server

Tags: weblogic, clover

I am struggling to get coverage of classes that are deployed into WebLogic server. I have them surely instrumented. The setup is that I have some classes in jars and some in unpacked form. When tests are executed against running application (some automated clicking), I can see some coverage for the classes packaged in jar, but I have no coverage for the unpacked classes. However, clover knows about those classes, I see them listed in clover database, but having no coverage.

Comment: Found a solution just minutes after I wrote this, but could help others too. The default Clover flushing policy is that the coverage data are stored when JVM is exiting. When I stopped my WL, all the expected coverage data appeared instantly.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+a+Flush+Policy